Excessive scrolling speed in edit mode
I've been experiencing an issue with Office Online Server:
When using edit mode, the scrolling is excessively fast compared to read mode. This makes it nearly impossible to highlight any text near the top or bottom of the page because even the slightest mouse movement causes the document to rapidly jump to the first or last page.
The problem worsens significantly when the browser is zoomed in to 150%, rendering edit mode almost unusable. This issue persists across all browsers I’ve tried.
How do I fix or temporarily work around that so that I could manage the scrolling speed in edit mode?

There is a known issue with Office Online Server where the scrolling speed in edit mode is significantly faster than in read mode. This issue makes it difficult to highlight text near the top or bottom of the page, as even a slight mouse movement can cause the document to jump to the first or last page. The problem is exacerbated when the browser is zoomed in to 150%, making edit mode almost unusable. Users have reported similar problems.
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a definitive fix for this issue yet. However, here are a few potential workarounds that might help manage the scrolling speed in edit mode:
Adjust Mouse Settings: Try adjusting the mouse settings in your operating system to reduce the scroll speed.
Use Keyboard Shortcuts: Instead of using the mouse to highlight text, try using keyboard shortcuts to navigate and select text.
Browser Extensions: Look for browser extensions that allow you to control the scrolling speed.

Thanks for your reply,
Adjust Mouse Settings: Adjusting mouse settings is not a workaround for us, as lots of people use the SharePoint intranet. It is not feasible to ask them to adjust their devices.
Use Keyboard Shortcuts: This is what I am doing, but we have users with varying IT capabilities. It's not feasible for everyone as well.
Browser Extensions: This has the same limitations as keyboard shortcuts.
Any other ideas?
